# What does this question mean?

Tags: meaning

"How might people consider about their career?"

Is it trying to ask what factors people may consider about their future career?

Comment: The wording is not idiomatic, IMHO. It's hard to tell what's meant without context.

Comment: I would guess that whoever wrote that question is not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Barmar That makes sense. Thank you~

Comment: @Barmar  I agree with both comments. I suspect the writer mixed up the meanings of *think* and *consider*. "*think about*" is often used but "*consider about*" is almost never used and is not idiomatic. Even in the unselective google ngram the ratio of use is about 1000:1.